# Matching text on multiple lines which begins and ends with some characters

Tags: java, regex

i have a source file something like

```
String some_words_come_here{
    //some string lines
    //some string lines
    //some string lines
    //some string lines
};
```

I am using it in java

```
Pattern.compile("(?m)^Strin.+\\};$", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
```

but this does not work well

with

```
Pattern.compile("(?m)^Strin.+", Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

i get the string just until the end of the line. because `.+` is quitting at the end of the line.

Comment: In what way does the first one "not work well?"

Comment: i mean that i get almoust the whole string.... It doesn, match the first accurence of };

I am sorry but i am new at regex and i don't know how to close that (?m) or how it should be closed.
I jeast read somewhere that it maches the begin of a new line also in a string and ^ means just the begin of the string.

Comment: So please post what you *do* get. `Pattern.MULTILINE` will make `^` and `$` match on start/end of line.

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern.compile("^String[^}]+\\};$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

should work unless there are `}` somewhere inside those lines (and unless there is whitespace before `String` or after `};`).

Explanation:

`^String` starts the match at the beginning of the line; match `String` literally.

`[^}]+` matches one or more occurrences of any character except `}`.

`\\};$` matches `};` and end-of-line. The backslash escapes the `}`, and since the backslash itself needs to be escaped in a Java string, too, you need two of them.

Comment: that works. could you please shortly explain how this works? especially at the [^}]+ part

Answer (score 0):

```
^String .*{\r*[^.*$]*};$
```

this works with Kodos tool.

a test in **Java**:

```
package mytest;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class Test4 {

     /**
      * @param args
      */
     public static void main(String[] args) {

      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
      sb.append("String some_words_come_here{").append("\n")
       .append("    //some string lines\n")
       .append("    //some string lines\n")
       .append("    //some string lines\n")
       .append("};\n");
      String regex = "^String .*\\{\\r*[^.*$]*\\};$";
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
      Matcher m = p.matcher(sb.toString());
      System.out.println(m.find());
      System.out.println(m.group(0));

     }

    }
```

output:

```
true
String some_words_come_here{
    //some string lines
    //some string lines
    //some string lines
};
```